Woocommerce admin search multiple product names
I'm wanting to search for multiple products in Woocommerce at once. So instead of searching one by one, I would like to type in a list of products separated by a comma or something similar.
I found this code by Bjorn that searches multiple SKUs at once, but I want to search by the product name instead. Is that possible?
/**
 * Use multiple sku's to find WOO products in wp-admin
 * NOTE: Use '|' as a sku delimiter in your search query. Example: '1234|1235|1236'
**/
function woo_multiple_sku_search( $query_vars ) {

    global $typenow;
    global $wpdb;
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $search_term = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );

        if (strpos($search_term, '|') == false) return $query_vars;

        $skus = explode('|',$search_term);

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR'
        );
        if(is_array($skus) && $skus) {
            foreach($skus as $sku) {
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => $sku,
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
        }

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'product',
            'meta_query'      => $meta_query
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if ( ! $posts ) return $query_vars;

        foreach($posts as $post){
          $query_vars['post__in'][] = $post->ID;
        }
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'woo_multiple_sku_search', 20 );


To search by product name instead of product SKU, you can use custom SQL query and search for post_title (WooCommerce products are a custom post type).
Also, you don't necessarily have to declare multiple globale variables separately, you can write them all in one instance by separating with "commas". (It doesn't make the biggest difference).
To search by , (comma) instead of |, or whatever symbol/seperator you want, you just have to change the indicator in the code on these 2 lines (e.g. '|' or ',' or '+'):
if (strpos($search_term, ',') === false) return $query_vars;

$terms = explode(',', $search_term);

Replace your existing code with the code below:
/*Search multiple product names in WOO products in wp-admin*/
function woo_multiple_name_search( $query_vars ) {
    global $typenow, $pagenow, $wpdb; // Declaring global variables

    // Check if we are in the admin area, on the product edit page, and a search is being performed
    if ( is_admin() && 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $search_term = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );

        // Check if the search term contains ',' indicating multiple search terms
        if (strpos($search_term, ',') === false) return $query_vars;

        $terms = explode(',', $search_term); // Split the search terms by ',' comma
        $post_ids = array(); // Initialize an array to hold the post IDs

        // Loop through each element in $terms array
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // Custom SQL query to search by product name
            $name_query = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
                WHERE post_type = 'product'
                AND post_title LIKE %s
            ", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($term) . '%'));

            // If there are results, add the post IDs to the array
            if ($name_query) {
                foreach ($name_query as $post) {
                    $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
                }
            }
        }

        // If no posts are found, return the original query vars
        if ( ! $post_ids ) return $query_vars;

        // Set the post__in parameter to the array of post IDs
        $query_vars['post__in'] = $post_ids;
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'woo_multiple_name_search', 20 );

To be added in your functions.php file of your active child theme. Tested and works on my end.
